# Dimensions dragged in filter pane do not slice scoped measures

Tags: ssas, mdx

A measure 'X' gets its value from different fact tables.Lets consider Time (Fiscal Week, Month)dimension and Channel dimension. For different combination of attributes in these two dimensions X will get its value from different tables as follows:

1. Week + Channel - gets from table FactTrafficByWeekChannel
2. Week  - gets from table FactTrafficByWeek
3. Month + Channel - gets from table FactTrafficByMonthChannel
4. Month  - gets from table FactTrafficByMonth

To achieve this I added these fact to cube and created a calculated measure and scope scripts to overwrite the scope. Following is the scope script statement:`

```
CALCULATE; 
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Y]
 AS (0), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard",
VISIBLE = 1;
Scope 
([Measures].[Y],[Dim Time].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].Members
 ) ; 
    This = [Measures].[X - Vw Fact Total Weekly Traffic];
End Scope ;
Scope 
([Measures].[Y],[Dim Time].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].Members,
[Dim Campaign].[Channel].[Channel].Members
 ) ; 
    This = [Measures].[X - Vw Fact Total Weekly Traffic By Channel];
End Scope ;
Scope 
 ([Measures].[Y],[Dim Time].[Fiscal Month].[Fiscal Month].Members
 ) ; 
    This = [Measures].[X - Vw Fact Monthly Traffic];
End Scope ;
Scope 
 ([Measures].[Y],[Dim Time].[Fiscal Month].[Fiscal Month].Members,
[Dim Channel].[Channel].[Channel].Members
 ) ; 
    This = [Measures].[X - Vw Fact Monthly Traffic By Channel];
End Scope ;
```

`

Above code works fine when corresponding dimension attributes are dragged in browsing pane but do not work when added to filter pane.
[Fiscal Week dimension dragged to browsing pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9J6t.png) this works. But 
[Fiscal Week dimension dragged to filter pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO2lF.png) does not work.
This is because attributes added to filter pane are added as sub-cube statements.
Is there a way to achieve this when attributes are dragged to filter pane as well? 
Time dimension Attribute relationship (as asked by Greg)
[image: Adding Time dimension Attribute relationship image]

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have 4 measure groups? Does summing up all channels for a week not match what you get from the week grain fact table? Do weeks roll up into fiscal months or not? Certainly it would simplify the problem and remove the need for any MDX if the by channel by week data could just roll up to the other three summary levels.

Comment: No, weeks data cannot be rolled up to fiscal month. It is basically new Visitors count measured differently for week, month and quarter too. To simplify the question I used week and month.

Comment: Problem is there is no way to know the attributes selected in filter pane in multidimensional cube where as there is a function 'IsFiltered' in DAX to identify whether an attribute in being filtered or not. Unfortunately there is no equivalent function in MDX

Comment: Is no expert available to help answer this question?

Comment: can you expand on the differences in how New Visitors Count is calculated by week vs. by month? I added an answer showing how to detect multiselect but suspect the 4+ grains of measures will be nearly impossible to get right. But if you explain New Visitor Count maybe there is a more straightforward way.

Comment: For a given week if a user has not visited with in -63 days then he is considered as a new visitor, similarly for month and quarter. there is a possibility of visitors may be counted redundantly when you roll up weeks data to month or quarter. Hence we need to maintain separate tables for each (Fiscal Week/Month/Quarter)

Comment: Why not have a fact table with one row per day per channel per visitor. A row should only appear when that visitor is new (hasn't visited in 63 days). Then the measure is a distinct count of VisitorID rather than a sum or a count. Would that return accurate results at the day, week, month, and quarter level?

Answer (score 1):

One way is using dynamic named set as described in this [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170226000233/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/08/25/mdx-in-katmai-dynamic-named-sets.aspx) in the "Using dynamic sets to detect subselects" section.

Add this to the bottom of your existing MDX script:

```
Create dynamic named set CurrentCube.[SelectedWeeks] as [Dim Time].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].Members;

Scope 
 ([Measures].[Y],[Dim Time].[Fiscal Month].[All],
[Dim Time].[Fiscal Week].[All],
[Dim Channel].[Channel].[All]
 ) ; 
    This = iif(SelectedWeeks.Count<[Dim Time].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].Members.Count,[Measures].[X - Vw Fact Total Weekly Traffic],0);
End Scope ;
```

But the problem with that approach is that it is going to get totally out of control checking all the permutations of single select on channel vs multi select on week, etc. And it will likely be slow.

Instead I would recommend removing the Create Member statement for Y from your MDX script and adding a new measure to your "by channel by week" measure group. Call the new physical measure Y and make it a Sum and connect it to a new SQL column that returns 0 on every row. This is just a placeholder measure you will do scoped assignments against. Why physical? When you make a scoped assignment on a physical measure at the channel level for example that assignment aggregates up. (Assignments to calc measures don't aggregate up.) This helps solve the multiselect issue. You assign at the channel level for example and then the All channel number is correct even under multiselect.

That being said, I am not optimistic you will be able to figure out the correct order of scoped assignments so that all 4 of your measures show up where you want with proper multiselect handling. But feel free to try.

One tip is to use Freeze([Measures].[Y], [Dim Time].[Fiscal Month].[All]) after one scoped assignment to months if you are happy with that portion of the cube but find subsequent scoped assignments are changing parts you were happy with.

If you need further help include a screenshot of the Attribute Relationships tab for Dim Time.

Comment: Dynamic set and comparison of selected weeks and total entries has been really helpful. But when I select only month in filter pane.SelectedWeeks set will get the weeks of selected month.In following code first IIF condition satisfies and shows weeks data,rather it is supposed to take months data
This = 
    IIF(
    SelectedWeeks.Count < [Dim Time].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].Members.Count
    ,SUM([Measures].[X - Fact Weekly Traffic])
    ,IIF(
    SelectedMonths.Count < [Dim Time].[Fiscal Month].[Fiscal Month].Members.Count
    ,SUM([Measures].[X - Fact Monthly Traffic])
    ,0
    )
    );

Comment: True. That is part of the complexity in detecting multiselect on week and month levels of the same dimension. You explained that very succinctly. That's one of the reasons I'm not optimistic you will succeed with your current design.